# htaccess 301 redirect with question mark

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have list of URL (600 approximately) that needs to be redirected, few URL are:

```
Redirect 301 /assets?/elfinder1?/elfinder.html http://www.example.com/swiftkanban/
Redirect 301 /backup?/elfinder?/elfinder.html http://www.example.com/swiftkanban/
Redirect 301 /blog?/xmlrpc.php http://www.example.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /blog.feed?type=rss http://www.example.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /m?/ http://www.example.com/swiftkanban/
Redirect 301 /m/ http://www.example.com/swiftkanban/
Redirect 301 /mobile?/ http://www.example.com/swiftkanban/
Redirect 301 /mobile/ http://www.example.com/swiftkanban/
Redirect 301 /SgjRY?/blog?/16-david-blog?/63-who-owns-kanban.html http://www.example.com/blog/who-owns-kanban/
Redirect 301 /support?/about.html http://www.example.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 /support?/about_us http://www.example.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 /support?/aboutus http://www.example.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 /support?/company http://www.example.com/about-us/the-team/
Redirect 301 /support?/contact.html http://www.example.com/contact-us/
Redirect 301 /support?/contact_us http://www.example.com/contact-us/
Redirect 301 /support?/contactus http://www.example.com/contact-us/
```

The problem is, I cannot do wildcard redirect, and this redirect rule does not work, I tried escaping the question mark using `\` but this does not seem to work, can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` directive cannot match query string. You need to use `mod_rewrite` based rules and use a `RewriteCond` directive as example below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog\?/xmlrpc\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/blog/? [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog\.feed\?type=rss [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/blog/? [L,NE,R=301]
```

Trailing `?` after `/blog/` is for removing pre-existing query string. If you want query string after redirect then remove `?` from target URL.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)